# How to convert a Python dictionary to a MySQL type?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am trying to store a Python dictionary in a MySQL Database. I get errors like the ones listed below:

```
AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_dict_to_mysql'

    raise TypeError("Python '{0}' cannot be converted to a "
TypeError: Python 'dict' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'dict' cannot be converted to a MySQL type'dict' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

My current code is:

```py
config = {'ban_message': 'test'}

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Dashboard (guild_id, configs) VALUES (%s, %s)", (638178402310029322, config))
```

any suggestions will be useful!

Comment: In what field type? string? You need to serialize it into a format such as JSON. You can store json in a string field, but I would recommend using jsonb

Comment: The `configs` column is a `VARCHAR` so yes, a string. How would I serialize it into a JSON format, and I've never heard of jsonb.

Comment: `json.dumps(config)`. Sorry, it's just called [json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#:~:text=MySQL%20handles%20strings%20used%20in,utf8%20are%20subsets%20of%20utf8mb4%20.) in mysql. Postgres calls it jsonb

Comment: I just tried that with json, I get the error: `mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'guild_id' at row 1` and my code is: `config = {'ban_message': 'test'}

json_obj = json.dumps(config, indent=4)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Dashboard (guild_id, configs) VALUES (%s, %s)", (638178402310029322, json_obj))`
do you maybe have Discord so we can talk more conveniently?

Comment: What is the `guild_id` data type? The number you are trying to use is bigger the max value for an int type

Comment: Ah yes! That was the issue, changing it over from `INT` to `BIGINT` worked!